# Celery: Custom Base class/child class based task not showing up under app.tasks

Tags: python, task, celery

I'm trying to create some celery tasks as classes, but am having some difficulty. The classes are:

```
class BaseCeleryTask(app.Task):

def is_complete(self):
    """ default method for checking if celery task has completed. """
    # simply return result (since by default tasks return boolean indicating completion)

    try:
        return self.result
    except AttributeError:
        logger.error('Result not defined. Make sure task has run!')
        return False
```

```
class MacroReportTask(BaseCeleryTask):

def run(self, params):
    """ Override the default run method with signal factory run"""
    # hold on to the factory
    process = MacroCountryReport(params)
    self.result = process.run()
    return self.result
```

but when I initialize the app, and check app.tasks (or run worker), app doesn't seem to have these above tasks in its registry. Other function based tasks (`using app.task() decorator`) seem to be registered fine.

I run the above task as:

```
process = SignalFactoryTask()
process.delay(params)
```

Celery worker errors with the following message:
`Received unregistered task of type None`.

I think the issue I'm having is: how do I add custom classes to the task registry as I do with regular function based tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into the exact same issue, took hours to find the solution cause I'm 90% sure it's a bug. In your class tasks, try the following

```
class BaseCeleryTask(app.Task):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "[modulename].BaseCeleryTask"

class MacroReportTask(app.Task):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "[modulename].MacroReportTask"
```

It seems registering it with the app still has a bug where the name isn't automatically configured. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have to test, but will let you know if it works!